# Good Windows tool to generate a report of PC hardware

Tags: directx, hardware, diagnostics

I have used dxdiag before, but I would prefer to point potential users to some tool that's a bit simpler, that they can just run and email me the output.

As well as obvious things like CPU, RAM, graphics, DirectX version and Windows version, I also need to know if ExpressCard (a laptop standard) is supported.

I know this isn't quite a programming question, but it's critical to establishing a way to tell users if their hardware supports our software before we deploy it.

Comment: Why the close votes? If you don't think deployment and testing is part of software development, I pity your users ;)

Answer (score 2):

System Information tool (`msinfo32`). Comes standard with the OS; supports bunch of [command-line switches](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300887) as well, allowing you to automate it.

In particular, you can tell the users to just run the following command and email you the resulting `.txt` file:

```
msinfo32 /report "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\configuration.txt"
```

Or if you want a subset, just filter it out based on the categories.

Not sure where is the info about the ExpressCard in it, but it should be in there somewhere.

Comment: Any idea where I'd look for ExpressCard?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a machine that supports ExpressCard right now, so I can't look it up. Just run the full report on a machine you know has it and look in the resulting file. Or beter yet, open `msinfo32` in GUI mode and look around.

Answer (score 0):

All this information will be available through the [Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

There are some microsoft provided examples available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Writing our own app is a bad idea. Not only is it a classic example of Not Invented Here, but then we face getting an untrusted app onto corporate networks.

Comment: @John:  Fair enough ... good luck finding one that does everything you want.